# Microsoft Visual Studio error HRESULT: 0xC0010014 (can not execute SSIS package)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

The setup is a VM on the cloud. The functioning project was copied. Once I open this copy and try to execute a package, it throws this error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio error HRESULT: 0xC0010014 (can not execute SSIS package)

This is the entirety of the output window:

```
------ Build started: Project: Macrodio (SQL Server 2014), Configuration: Debug ------
```

````
Starting project consistency check ...
Error : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0010014 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0010014
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.LoadPackage(String FileName, Boolean loadNeutral, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents100 events, Boolean loadNeutral)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents100 events, Boolean loadNeutral)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildItemInfo.Update(DateTime lastWriteTime, PackageItem packageItem, Project project, String projectDirectory)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildItemInfo..ctor(String name, DateTime lastWriteTime, PackageItem packageItem, Project project, String projectDirectory)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildValidator.RefreshCache(PackageItem item)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildValidator.CheckBuildItem(PackageItem item)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.ProjectBuildValidator.CheckConsistency(String& errors, String buildLogFullName)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
Build complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ========== ```
````

Comment: check this:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2010/06/16/why-package-load-error-0xc0010014-in-cpackageloadfromxml-error-appears-while-trying-to-run-an-ssis-package/

Comment: Let' start with the basics - do you have SQL Server Data Tools (2014) installed on the machine? If you rebuild the project, do any errors show up? Is the project password protected or something unusual?

Comment: @billinkc yes, there are SQL Server Data Tools. Tried to rebuild the project. Here is an error: `------ Rebuild All started: Project: Macrodio (SQL Server 2014), Configuration: Debug ------
Build started: SQL Server Integration Services project: Full ...
Error : Unexpected build error: Access to the path 'D:\Projects\Macrodio-SSIS - Anna\bin\Debug\Macrodio.ispac' is denied..
Make sure that the product is installed properly.
Build complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: @billinkc yes, the project is password protected

Comment: The bit to key in on for future debugging is `Access to the path 'D:\Projects\Macrodio-SSIS - Anna\bin\Debug\Macrodio.ispac'`  Change the build from Debug to Release and then see if it will run/build

Comment: I see the dropdown for Solutions configuration, and have changed it from debug to release. However, when rebuilding the project, Config is still Debug, getting the same error. How do I change it? (Thanks for answering noob questions)

Comment: It'll be a few hours before I'm in front of a machine with SSIS on it. The quick and dirty you can try is to close visual studio and then try to manually delete `D:\Projects\Macrodio-SSIS - Anna\bin\Debug\Macrodio.ispac`  The other place to look at changing between debug and release is the top center-ish toolbar. At the core of it, what we're trying to do is release the lock some process has put on the ispac file. Using the Release build will have the IS engine use a new ispac and closing VS _should_ close any background processes with their grubby finger holding the file open